# Select last 3 rows of each item

Tags: mysql

i have two tables `raw_materials` and `raw_materials_moves`.

`raw_materials` has fields

```
id, name
```

`raw_materials_moves` has this fields

```
id, raw_material_id, price, created
```

so, i need to `select` last 3 moves of each raw material

i have this query but doesn´t work

```
SELECT a.*, b.price, b.created
FROM raw_materials a
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT price, raw_material_id, created FROM raw_material_moves ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 3) b
    ON b.raw_material_id=a.id
ORDER BY a.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I would agree mostly with @chetan on the usage of variables to get this job done.

[Here is one of the best articles](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) that I have come across on the subject and different ways to handle it.. ranging from easy to hard.

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to user cursor with DESC (or) by fetching in reverse order

Comment: i´m really new on Mysql , can you give me some example please?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT r1.id,name,raw_material_id 

FROM raw_materials r1, raw_materials_move r2

 WHERE r1.id=r2.id ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

last 3 moves by created (I assume date) of each raw material

```
select * from 
  (select a.id,a.price,a.created, 
          if(@mat=a.raw_material_id,@num:=@num+1,@num:=1) rank,
          @mat:=a.raw_material_id
     from raw_materials_moves a, (select @num:=0) b   
     order by a.raw_material_id,a.created desc) temp
where rank <=3;
```

see [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d806/5)

Comment: do you have any email? so i can send u the SQls of the tables, i ran the query but it returns  the entire table of moves.

Comment: i think this query has an issue with the DATETIME fields, sometimes it works and others don´t :s

Answer (score -3):

Reverse-sort it (i.e. `... SORT BY somefield DESC`) and then get the first 3 (by appending `LIMIT 3`)